# Make a VPN with my Ubuntu 15.10 VPS?

Tags: vpn

I have a VPS somewhere running Ubuntu server 15.10 What I want to do is turn it into a VPN so that i can use it like any other VPN. I have searched online but found no tutorials on how to do so. Does anyone here know how I can turn my VPS into a VPN?

Comment: Maybe [OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't search very hard then... I present to you: [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/).

Then asking Google for "openvpn how to install*, gives me this.  A cursory glance over one of this [search hit](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-14-04), tells me it's rather complete. (Yes, I have a few like these running: two on AWS and one on at edit.at)

Comment: i thought openvpn was just another vpn service so sorry and thx

Comment: It also is, but it is totally open source and anyone can install it.  Granted, it's not for newbies, but it is well documented.   You could also have looked at the available packages in the repos, but I have to admit that is a bit harder and not as straightfoward.  Happy VPNning!